# Wikidata query to get all values for specific properties

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I have a list of properties, let's say P8839, P21, P91 and P1039.

I'd like to query Wikidata and get all unique value labels that belong to these properties.

```
SELECT ?itemLabel WHERE {   
    ?itemLabel wdt:P8839 ?cui.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

What I have returns ids of one page where the property is included. I'm rather new to queries so I'm not sure what needs to change to include all properties and unique labels.

Comment: Is that what you want? https://w.wiki/5UuD (it only queries the first two properties as the query doesn’t finish otherwise)

Comment: Yes, that's very helpful thank you! What's ?s ?p ?o. in your query if you don't mind clarifying?

Comment: I posted an answer (where I renamed the variables). `?s ?p ?o` matches all triples in the graph; they are just variables, it doesn’t matter how they are named (in this case, I chose them as shorthand for [subject, predicate, object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_triple#Subject,_predicate_and_object)). As `?p` is getting restricted in `VALUES`, of course it only matches the triples where the predicate is one of the listed ones. – Could you please add the [tag:sparql] tag to your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

This query lists the distinct English labels of all values of the properties listed in `VALUES`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?valueLabel
WHERE {  

  VALUES (?property) {
    (wdt:P1039)
    (wdt:P8839)
    #(wdt:P21)
    #(wdt:P91)
  }  
  
  ?s ?property ?value.
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

(Note that you get a "Query timeout limit reached" in WDQS if you include all four properties, which is why I commented out the last two. Unless you can add further restrictions, you might have to run the query multiple times for different properties.)

If you also want to get a link to the actual values, you can add `?value` to the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?value ?valueLabel
```